# How to get last value of the input with some dynamic class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple inputs and a button. When I click the button the active class from first input goes to next input. What I want to do is get the value of previous input with that class after button click.

How to do that?

```js
$('.question').prev('.selected input').val();
```

```html
<form action="final.php" method="post">
  <input name="intr_id" value="0" type="hidden">
  <p class="question selected" id="intreb_1">
    <input name="intr1" value="" type="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_2">
    <input name="intr2" value="" type="hidden">Sed tempus hendrerit orci, sed interdum quam rhoncus quis?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_3">
    <input name="intr3" value="" type="hidden">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_4">
    <input name="intr4" value="" type="hidden">Suspendisse hendrerit, nibh eu fringilla finibus, lacus lectus elementum nunc, sed molestie sapien orci id erat?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_5">
    <input name="intr5" value="" type="hidden">Sed tempus hendrerit orci, sed interdum quam rhoncus quis?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_6">
    <input name="intr6" value="" type="hidden">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_7">
    <input name="intr7" value="" type="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_8">
    <input name="intr8" value="" type="hidden">Sed tempus hendrerit orci, sed interdum quam rhoncus quis?</p>
  <p class="question " id="intreb_9">
    <input name="intr9" value="" type="hidden">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus?</p>
  <p class="question  last" id="intreb_10">
    <input name="intr10" value="" type="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
  <div class="answer_buttons">
    <a class="nu" href="">No</a>
    <a class="da" href="">Yes</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: would be great if you can share markup

Comment: Did you mean `input` with class `selected`?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, I added the HTML too.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, NO, I mean parent div with class selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if my understanding is correct, you have:

```
Input 1, wrapped by some container
Input 2 wrapped by some container
```

After filling Input 1, the Input 2 container gets a "selected" class and, at that point, you want to see what's the value of Input 1?

First, have in mind that this is a bad solution design as a whole, because your business logic gets mixed up (and dependent!) with your presentation.

The cleanest way to do it is to have both containers have some generic class like "input-field-container". That way, after having the 2nd container being also selected, its class will be "input-field-container selected". Then, using jQuery, you'd have:

```
$(".input-field-container.selected")
    .prev(".input-field-container")
        .children("input").first().val()
```

Note that you may have to replace children with find if your actual input is wrapped in intermediate elements between the container and the input.

Translation: Get me the selected container, then get the first container above it, then get its first child input and get its value.

And again, this is a bad approach - values to your inputs should be synchronized with a model that should take care of reading them and it shouldn't be depending on such a logic.

Comment: What kind of model do you mean?

Comment: A model as in a data model of the form and a controller that processes this data. For example, an OnBlur handler could update the model and call additional logic that would take decisions based on what data is filled in the form up to now. Because now, guess what will happen if you need to insert another Input between the two :)

Comment: Can you please give me a practical example?!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `var val = $(".question.selected input[type='hidden']").val()` before the code which transfers the class to the next input will get you the value.

Comment: I dont have selected class on the input. I have it on the p tag.

Comment: Changed my code accordingly. This will select the p tag with the class 'question' and 'selected' and then get the value of the hidden field.